# Reformating Drive on Windows Server 2012R2 Non-GUI

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Recently installed 2012R2 accidentally installed the non-GUI server core edition and am looking to format the drive and reinstall using the GUI version. Attempted to reformat via cmd line "DiscPart" but it does not allow you to reformat the current drive OS is on. Any recommendations on how to reformat drive and do a clean install? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Reboot from CD/iso and start a new install from scratch ?

Comment: Umm... yeah... what krisFR said...

Comment: @joeqwerty Why need to reformat? we can install gui on server core right?

Comment: @daisy: Because the OP stated that he wanted to format and reinstall?